# Getting viewport size on a mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, viewport, dimensions

On my Optimus One LG mobile, I get "700" both for the window.innerWidth and document.documentElement.clientWidth variables, whereas I know that the resolution of this mobile is 320px in width that is quite low resolution.

The page where I display these variable values has  in its header.

Why do I not get 320 instead of 700 ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` might help, if you have not already added a viewport meta.

Comment: I had already this except for initial-scale=1 and maximum-scale=1. But even this doesn't solve the problem and I still get 700.